# PHP mail form : the mail is blank

Tags: php, html, email

I'm a beginner, and I would like to make a PHP mail form like that :

[image: Screenshot]

But it doesn't work, I receive the mail but there is anything in it, and I don't understand why :/

Here is the HTML code for my form :

```
<form method=POST action=formmail.php >
    <input type=hidden name=subject value=formmail>


<p>Pseudo* :<br>
    <span class="padding1"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>Email* :<br>
    <span class="your-email padding1"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>
<p>Link of the GIF* :<br>
    <span class="link-url padding1"><input type="url" name="link-url" value="" aria-invalid="false"></span> </p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Send"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://s584101063.onlinehome.fr/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Envoi en cours ..." style="visibility: hidden;"></p>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is my PHP code :

```
    <?php
$TO = "saintscorporation@gmail.com";

$h = "From: " . $TO;

$message = "";

while (list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
$message .= "$key : $val\n";
}

mail($TO, $subject, $message, $h);

Header("Location: http://gifmyday.com/index.html");

?>
```

Comment: while (list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) this part is kind of yuck, what is this $HTTP_POST_VARS - it's not set in the above code only used. Id suggest doing foreach( $HTTP_POST_VARS as $key => $value ) instead

Comment: Your CSS code is php

Comment: progsource : shame on me I'm tired, I modified,

Comment: @progsource - nice catch!

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix : I'm trying it, thanks for it, get in touch when I will have the result

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix The mail is still blank :/

Comment: @newbie - right but what is the value of $HTTP_POST_VARS, do print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS);  I suspect you want this $_POST

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I was following a tutorial, and I didn't understand this HTTP_POST_VARS, because I'm currently learning PHP, please what does it means ? And what does it implies in my case ? Thanks a lot

Comment: $http_post_vars has been deprecated/obsolete for a LONG time. you should NEVER use it in any new code.

Comment: Oh, so it was an obsolete tutorial, what is currently replacing this ?

Comment: @newbie - it means nothing more the the $TO - as in it's a variable, unlike $TO it's not assigned a value in your code $TO = 'address';  so that would imply it has no value, based on the name I figure it's the $_POST array, which is a global variable - which is why it has the "$_" so that will contain the post ( method=post ) of a form on that page.

Comment: This would make your tutorial complete $HTTP_POST_VARS = $_POST;

Answer (score 1):

Adding the headers I put in the following code should help.

```
<?php
$TO = "saintscorporation@gmail.com";

// The headers have been changed a bit
$h = "From: " . $TO . "\r\n";
$h .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n" . 
    "Content-type: text/html charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";

$message = "";

while (list($key, $val) = each($HTTP_POST_VARS)) {
$message .= "$key : $val\n";
}

mail($TO, $subject, $message, $h);

Header("Location: http://gifmyday.com/index.html");

?>
```